# how to add/access a JS compiled from GWT to/in another external html/JS project

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am tasked to compile the gwt project(which doesnot include HTML CSS) into JS files and add the same to an external JS/HTML file( which is in different project).

here is the java code which has to be compiled:
1. Client class:

```
 package com.dell.supportassist.gwt.collectionReport.client;
```

import org.timepedia.exporter.client.Export;
import org.timepedia.exporter.client.Exportable;

@Export("HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld  implements  Exportable {

```
public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

}

2. EntryPoint Class:

   package com.dell.supportassist.gwt.collectionReport.client;

import org.timepedia.exporter.client.Export;
import org.timepedia.exporter.client.Exportable;

@Export("HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld  implements  Exportable {

```
public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

}

My issue is, once the above gwt project/classes are complied, i want to access 'sayHello()' method in ma external javascript like this:

```
var person = hello.sayHello();
        system.log(person);
```

But this is throwing a run time error saying 'hello' is not defined.

P.S I am trying to use the GWT compiled JS in an external HTML, JS Present in Durandaljs Framework.

Comment: You should fire ExporterUtil.exportAll();

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this kind of stuff for quite some time but you could achieve this using [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html), which allows you to write native JS in GWT. From JSNI you can reference your GWT methods. That way you could define a function (on window, most typically) which would then become available to regular JS. From this JSNI-method you can reference your GWT/Java code.

Code example:

```
public class MyModule implements EntryPoint {
    static {
        export();
    }

    /**
     * Makes our setData method accessible from plain JS
     */
    private static native void export() /*-{
        $wnd.setData = @my.package.MyModule::setData(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;);
    }-*/;

    private static void setData(JavaScriptObject javaScriptObject) {
        // this method is now reachable as window.setData
    }
}
```